# Custom Gnosis Safe App, Github/ Magic Link OAuth Login Redirect

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, authentication, gnosis-chain

We use Github & Magic Link as the main way to authenticate our users.

Based on the redirect url we have on our Github OAuth app or Magic link settings, we redirect our users to a static url.

Right now it looks like we cannot OAuth at all within a custom safe app with both of our main authentication. Since safe app links seem to be dynamic, we also cannot predict a URL we want to redirect.

Im sure somebody encountered already this issue, but I didn't find anything.
Thanks for the help.